# Counting symbols without spaces in bash

Tags: bash, count, wc

I want to create script which will count symbols from string "word blah-blah word one more time word again". It will count symbols before "word" only and every "word" should be written to new string. So output of script should looks like that:

```
word 0 ## (no symbols)
word 9 ##blah-blah
word 11 ##one more time
```

All i got in this moment:

```
#!/bin/bash
$word="word blah-blah word one more time word again"
echo "$word" | grep -o word
```

Output show me only "word" from $word. How i can count chars before "word"?

Comment: You mean count characters? Do this with `awk`. Set the record separator to `word`, then print `length($0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bash`solution:

```
word="word blah-blah word one more time word again"
c=0
for w in $word;do
  [[ $w != "word" ]] && (( c+= ${#w} )) && continue
  echo $w $c
  c=0
done
```

From `bash` *man*:

> ${#parameter}
>
> Parameter  length.  The length in characters of the value of parameter is substituted.  If parameter is * or @, the value substituted is the number of positional parameters.  If parameter is an array name subscripted  by  *or @, the value substituted is the number of elements in the array.

**Explanation**

`for w in $word;do` : Used to split the *word* string using blank spaces as separators into *single word* variables: *w*.

`[[ $w != "word" ]] && (( c+= ${#w} )) && continue`:  If `w` is not `word` store the number of characters in currentstring (`${#w}`) into `c` counter and proceed to next word (`continue`) without further processing.

When literal *word* is founded, just print the value of the counter and initialize it (`c=0`)

**Results**

```
word 0
word 9
word 11
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how this code (( c+= ${#w} )) counts  symbols without spaces?